# How to use Autolayout when removing element dynamically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have 2 buttons place next to each other and evenly spaced across the screen. At the minute they are both set to be evenly sized. Now one of those buttons needs to be removed on the fly so I would like to make the second button span all the way across after the first is removed. Problem is I am unsure if I can do this using Autolayout in Storyboard. Pretty basic example of how the buttons currently look.

> 20px - BUTTON 1 - 10px - BUTTON 2 - 20px

After

> 20px - BUTTON2 - 20px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first your view look like this.
20px - BUTTON 1 - 10px - BUTTON 2 - 20px
[image]
Below bottom button:

```
[self.buttonOneOutlet removeFromSuperview];
```

self.buttonTwoOutlet.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.buttonTwoOutlet attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:20.0]];
```

After that it look like [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add another constraint from your BUTTON 2 with lower priority than constraint to BUTTON 1 in storyboard.

[image: Something like that]

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to group the two buttons in a horizontal stack view. If you set the stack view's spacing to be 10, it will maintain the spacing between the buttons. Constrain the stack view's leading and trailing edges to get the 20 point offset on either side.

The useful thing about the stack view is that if you set button 1's `hidden` property to `YES`, it'll disappear and the stack view will take care of updating constraints. It would update its own content size to be large enough to hold button 2 only, and the 10 point spacing wouldn't have any effect. But then if you set button 1's `hidden` property to `NO`, it'll come back to the original state.